# How to monitor changes to a large file?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm using python to build a big tree in a server, and I need read a file to get data. When the file changes, I want to update my tree. Since the file is too big ,say 1G, then the cost time of reading and building the tree is too long, say 2 minutes. Python does not support "real multithreading". (I tried and made the server blocked), so I tried `multiprocessing`, but it takes up too many resources, and data shared between processes is bit hard.

So is there a proper way to monitor the file and build a new tree to replace the old one in the server?

Comment: When the file changes, do you want to read the whole thing, or are you looking for a way to read just the part that changed?

Comment: How your file looks like? If you could split it and read by chunks e.g. 10000 symbols - would this solve your problem ?

Comment: @JohnGordon I want to read the whole file. And I actually dot know which lines have changed.

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Maybe this can solve my problem, but I just worry about influencing the server when the qps becomes larger.

Comment: @PengHe take a look into [this guide](http://effbot.org/zone/wide-finder.htm), maybe it will be usefull for solving your problem